# Different form fields for add and change view in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I want to display different form fields for add and change view in Django admin.

If it is `add` then I am showing the form field `file_upload` and if it is `change` then I am showing model fields `cname` and `mname`

Code from admin.py

```
class couplingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('cname','mname')
    form = CouplingUploadForm #upload_file is here

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # Proper kwargs are form, fields, exclude, formfield_callback
        if obj: # obj is not None, so this is a change page
            kwargs['exclude'] = ['upload_file',]
        else: # obj is None, so this is an add page
            kwargs['exclude'] = ['cname','mname',]
        return super(couplingAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

If it is `add` then it's fine but if it is `change` view then I am getting all the fields ie cname,mname,upload_file.

Please suggest how can I remove `upload_file` from change view in admin.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

You can override the [`add_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_view) and [`change_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view) methods in your `ModelAdmin`:

```
class CouplingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('cname', 'mname')
    form = CouplingUploadForm  # upload_file is here

    def add_view(self, request, extra_content=None):
        self.exclude = ('cname', 'mname')
        return super(CouplingAdmin, self).add_view(request)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_content=None):
        self.exclude = ('upload_file',)
        return super(CouplingAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id)
```

Comment: The change_view is still showing `upload_file` field. Is it because that I called `form = CouplingUploadForm` before

Answer (score 7):

```
class couplingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('cname','mname')
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            fields=('upload_file',)
        else:
            fields =('cname','mname')
        return fields
```

Answer (score 1):

To use an entirely different form to add/change:

```py
class couplingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('cname','mname')

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=None, **kwargs):
        if not obj:
            # Use a different form only when adding a new record
            return CouplingUploadForm

        return super().get_form(request, obj=obj, change=change, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly. Not sure if it's a bug in django or this usage is not intended, but when I do this (use two different forms) then the form that actually gets rendered seems to be random. I think django might be storing the form types somewhere, not sure.